# pandas round() method is not working with mask

Tags: pandas, rounding, mask

In the following example I would like to obtain a dataframe, in which the numbers in all columns have 2 digits. However, after the masking, the .round() method is not applied to the third column, only to the first two:

```
l = pd.DataFrame([[1.111, 2.222], [3.333, 4.444], [5.555, 1.111], [2.222, 3.333]])
l2 = pd.Series([3.333, 4.444, 1.111, 3.333, 6.666])
l2.mask(l2<3, '', inplace=True)
l['test'] = l2
l.round(2)
```

Comment: `l.dtypes` should tell you; with `""`, the datatype of `l2` has changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @MustafaAydın suggests, the dtype of `l2` changed as soon as you replaced a float value with a string:

```
>>> l2
0    3.333
1    4.444
2    1.111
3    3.333
4    6.666
dtype: float64  # <- numeric series

>>> l2.mask(l2 < 3, '')
0    3.333
1    4.444
2         
3    3.333
4    6.666
dtype: object  # <- object series
```

This is why only the first 2 columns of `l` are rounded.

Note that the behavior is not the same between `Series.round` and `DataFrame.round`. The latter tries to round all numeric columns while the former throws an exception:

```
>>> l.assign(test=l2.mask(l2 < 3, '')).round(2)
      0     1   test
0  1.11  2.22  3.333
1  3.33  4.44  4.444
2  5.56  1.11       
3  2.22  3.33  3.333

>>> l2.mask(l2 < 3, '').round(2)
...
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Comment: OK, I see, so what would I need to change to get this to work?

Comment: Replace by 0 instead of ''.

Comment: I found a solution using l2.apply(lambda col:pd.to_numeric(col, errors='coerce')) from another thread.

Comment: Yes, that would work as well, but the cells should be empty.

Comment: In this case, replace by NaN then round and finally fillna('')